# A term for a 'vector' that only has an orientation, not a direction?

Tags: vectors, terminology

A 'vector' in $ℝ^2$ has a magnitude and a direction defined on [0, 2$\pi$). How would one describe a similar quantity, but with only an orientation defined on [0, $\pi$)? One example of this sort of axial data is astronomical observations of a polarization field, which typically are visualized by little line segments to indicate that they are indistinguishable under a 180 degree rotation. People sometimes refer to these as "vectors". "Vectors" is clearly incorrect, but what to call them?

Comment: What about [versor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_vector)?

Comment: "*A vector has a magnitude and a direction defined on $[0,2\pi)$*"  You apparently do not understand what a vector truly is.  [Vectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space) are much more general than what you appear to be familiar with.  The "direction" that people refer to would be the versor manooooh refers to, given a vector $v$ in a normed vector space the "direction" would be the unit length vector $\frac{v}{\|v\|}$, but even that doesn't necessarily make sense in all contexts.

Comment: That all being said, for the *very specific* example of the vectorspace of $\Bbb R^2$ which you seem to be working in (*as opposed to even a perhaps more important $\Bbb R^3$ or $\Bbb R^n$*), if you wanted to refer only to those vectors whose "orientation is in $[0,\pi)$", you could refer to these as "vectors from the upper half-plane" or "vectors with second component non-negative"

Comment: Essentially, you only care about the $1$-dimensional subspaces, and pick a unit length representative of each, belonging to the upper half plane. This fits in with the ideal of considering vectors *projectively*, and considering $\vec{v}$ to be "the same as" $\lambda \vec{v}$ for any scalar $\lambda$. In this way, you are referring to points in a projective plane, but "point" is probably too vague, while "point in a projective plane" too wordy.